# Adjusting images to screen

Tags: html, css, image, rows

I have made an image gallery, made up by two rows each with tree images. I've made my site responsive, but for some reason, the images does not resize/adjust according to the screen. I've attached the picture, and as is visible the images does not adjust to the screen. [Screen shot of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjWXb.png)

```css
.image3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 370px;
  border: 5px solid;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3">
    <img src="img/static1.squarespace2.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3">
    <img src="img/apple-iphone-8.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3"> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="img/iphone-8-concept.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3">
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3">
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image does not resize because you gave them a absolute width. If you give the element a `max-width` and `max-height` of 100% it should be responsive. So like this:

```css
.image3 {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="img/static1.squarespace2.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="img/apple-iphone-8.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3" /> 
  </div>


  <div class="row">

    <img src="img/iphone-8-concept.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />

  </div>
```

Pixels are not responsive to the screen's size

**Note: See response from MarioZ below**

Comment: That's ok for big images to fit small containers, yet a relative size (or min-size) is needed for small images fitting bigger containers.

Answer (score 0):

Why would they?

You can use

```
max-width: 100%; /* or 33% or whatever you need */
```

to let it shrink when the screen has less width, but right now it will always be the size you specified.

---

Also "responsiveness" mainly refers to having different layouts for different screen widths, which results in optimized layouts for both mobile and desktop. Having three images next to each other doesn't seem very responsive. Rather I would decrease the number of images in each row.

Like this:

```css
.image3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 370px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="Iphone" class="image3" /> 
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the desired result.

Comment: How is using `max-width` not the desired result?

Comment: Yeah that is a lot better - thanks! The problem is that the assignment said specifically: 6 images that should be displayed in two rows :/

Comment: This is not even responsive and if this solution is a lot better then you clearly don't know what responsiveness is Maria.

Comment: Well I only gave the starting html. I don't want to design anything for you, but you can restrict the amount of elements in a row to a maximum of 3, which would result in the "6 images in 2 rows" for desktop, but still offer a responsive layout.

Comment: VXp I do know what responsive is, but I am very NEW in all of this, so excuse me if I sometimes mix up certain terms. I just needed the pictures to adjust to the screen size - that was all...  You do not need to patronize me. I am very glad for the help and constructive feedback though :)

Comment: @Maria I'm not it's just that this solution doesn't go along with your question.

Comment: @VXp How? I posted how he can make it shrink and also addressed that it is not really responsive as he said he is designing responsive. I don't think I addressed anything not relevant to the post, did I?

Comment: @SourceOverflow 1. this is not responsive & 2. "break-ing" img's is not among "requirements"

Comment: 1. the second solution is responsive. Not nice responsive, but like I said I didn't want to do a whole layout
2. it is not, but telling someone "You can do it that way, but that doesn't fit with the rest of your design (as it is claimed to be responsive)" is helpful and was an addition to the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're giving a fixed size to your images using `px` units. If you want your images to be responsive, to adapt their size, you need to use relative units. Being the most common:

- Relative to the container: percentaje **%**
- Relative to the container font-size: **em**
- Relative to the root element font-size: **rem**
- Relative to the viewport size: **vw** and **vh** (equivalent to 1% of
  the viewport measure)

You should wrap each image in an individual div `class:wrapper` and give the div a relative width.

```css
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.image3 {
  display:block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.row {
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 33.33%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/80/80/any" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/120/120/any" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/80/80/any" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/120/120/any" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" alt="Iphone" class="image3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe it's a good idea to use css **flexbox** or **grid** too.

Comment: @Maria I have just updated the answer with more detail ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this code. here i used bootstrap...
copy whole code.. and save as page.html
then check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
 </div>  

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  </div>

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" class="img-responsive"> 
  </div>

</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
  </div>
  </div> 

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Aah thanks! I've though about using bootstrap actually, but I havn't really looked into it yet, but I definitely will. It seems like it is a very used framework these days.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image to be responsive there are 2 main things you need to do:

1. never set both width and height, just set width.
2. don't use pixels to set the width use percentages

In your case you have 3 images so divide 100% in 3 which is about 33%, so give the images the size of 33% (or a little less if the container doesn't have box-sizing: border-box;)  and they will adjust nicely.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tips - thats a good rule to remember! I actually started out by setting the image size to 33.1 %, but then for some reason I deleted it - should have stuck to that :D

Comment: - "don't use pixels to set the width use percentages"
Pixels are perfectly fine to use...

Comment: If you want it to be responsive and adjust size as the window changes, as was the question, you need relative units, pixel sizes are for having one set size. If that's what you want pixels are ok, but if you want it to be truly responsive you need relative units.